# How to detect sql table updates with multiple open browsers or windows?

Tags: html, sql

-I have an html page with a textbox element with autocomplete feature.
-The autocomplete list is filled from Mysql table called X.
-A user can open this page from multiple browsers or windows at the same time.
-The user is able to add new records or update existing records to table X from the same page.

Now as he adds new records I want the other window or the browser detect that a change happened in the table and refresh the autocomplete list so it is visible there too.

How can I achieve this?
I am thinking of checking if the table changed on every keypress of the textbox, but I am afraid that's gonna slow the page.
The other solution I was thinking is can I apply a trigger in this case?

I know this is used alot for example you can open your gmail account from multiple browser or window and if you edit anything you will be able to see it from the rest.
I appreciate your help as I searched alot about this but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL trigger wouldn't help here - that's just for running logic inside the DB. The issue is that you don't have a way to *push* changes down to the client (except perhaps Web sockets or something, but that would probably be a lot of work), so you would have to resort to polling the server for updates. Doing so on key press might be excessive - perhaps on focus and/or periodically (every minute?)? To lessen the load, you could have the client make the request using some indicator of the state that it last successfully fetched, and have the server only return changes (deletions and insertions - an update would be a combination of the two) so then rather than the full list every time it is only a delta.

Within a single browser you may be able to incorporate local storage as well, but that won't help across multiple browsers.

Another option would be to not store the autocomplete options locally and always fetch from the server (on key press). Typically you would not send the request when the input length is less than some threshold (say, 3 characters) to try to keep the result size reasonable. You can also throttle the key press event so that multiple presses in quick succession get combined into only one request sent, and also store and cancel any outstanding asynchronous requests before sending a new one. This approach will guarantee you always get the most current data from the database, and while it will add a degree of latency to the autocomplete in my experience it is rarely an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and has many, many answers. It also depends on your database back end. Among many is couple of note worthy ones, if you use a Bus of some sort in the back end you can push your change to the db then to the bus and your web client can consume it from there so it know to refresh. The other is use a trigger (if you're using MSSQL) to push the change, using a CLR assembly your created to an MSMQueue and consume it from there, it'll reduce the constant polling for the db. Personally I always use the Bus for this kind of things but it depends on your set up.

Comment: I am using MySql I edited that, what's the other things which is unclear so I can edit ?

Comment: @NatalieBoudakian I'm not sure the DB flavor matters much for this purpose since the "hard" part is client-server synchronization. I'm not sure that your question is really unclear, it's just that it is somewhat broad. There are a *lot* of factors that come into play depending on your requirements so only a general approach can be provided. As you get started if you have specific questions more direct answers may be possible.